# Unable to perform shift operations in pandas with multiple product names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I've written a code which will groupby and get the difference. Then dividing the difference and SUM_PROD_SELL_QTY with shifting the row by 1.

Below is the code

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'PRODUCT_NAME':['HYDT300ML','HYDT300ML', 'NEW', 'HYDT300ML', 'NEW', 'HYDT300ML','HYDT300ML'],
           'WEEK_NUMBER':[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3],
           'PROMO_DEPTH':[0, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.3],
           'SUM_PROD_SELL_QTY':[6, 29, 11, 10, 19, 20, 45]})

df_groupby = df.groupby(['PRODUCT_NAME', 'WEEK_NUMBER', 'PROMO_DEPTH'])['SUM_PROD_SELL_QTY'].sum().reset_index()

# Groupby the PRODUCT_NAME, WEEK_NUMBER, PROMO_DEPTH and get the difference in SUM_PROD_SELL_QTY
df_groupby['difference'] = df_groupby.groupby(['PRODUCT_NAME', 'PROMO_DEPTH'])['SUM_PROD_SELL_QTY'].diff()

# Create a uplift and downlift values with it's precentages with the reference of 29-10=19 where 19 has to be divided by it's previous SUM_PROD_SELL_QTY value i.e.29, then 19/29, in the same way for every row.
df_groupby['uplift_downlift_percentage'] = df_groupby['difference'] / df_groupby['SUM_PROD_SELL_QTY'].shift(1)

df_groupby
```

But the output it's returning is different. Below is the output

```
     PRODUCT_NAME   WEEK_NUMBER PROMO_DEPTH SUM_PROD_SELL_QTY   difference  uplift_downlift_percentage
0           HYDT300ML   1   0.0 6   NaN      NaN
1           HYDT300ML   1   0.3 29  NaN      NaN
2           HYDT300ML   1   0.5 20  NaN      NaN
3           HYDT300ML   2   0.3 10  -19.0   -0.950000
4           HYDT300ML   3   0.3 45  35.0    3.500000
5           NEW         1   0.3 11  NaN      NaN
6           NEW         2   0.3 19  8.0      0.727273
```

I'm trying to get the division value of 19/29 because it comes under same PROMO_DEPTH which is 0.3 and same PRODUCT_NAME which is HYDT300ML. But in the above output it's taking -19 from difference and 20 from SUM_PROD_SELL_QTY. How to groupby on PRODUCT_NAME, WEEK_NUMBER and PROMO_DEPTH? The Expected output is below

```
         PRODUCT_NAME   WEEK_NUMBER PROMO_DEPTH SUM_PROD_SELL_QTY   difference  uplift_downlift_percentage
0           HYDT300ML   1   0.0 6   NaN      NaN
1           HYDT300ML   1   0.3 29  NaN      NaN
2           HYDT300ML   1   0.5 20  NaN      NaN
3           HYDT300ML   2   0.3 10  -19.0   -0.655
4           HYDT300ML   3   0.3 45  35.0    3.500000
5           NEW         1   0.3 11  NaN      NaN
6           NEW         2   0.3 19  8.0      0.727273
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shift should occur group-wise:

```
df_groupby['uplift_downlift_percentage'] = df_groupby['difference']/df_groupby.groupby(['PRODUCT_NAME', 'PROMO_DEPTH'])['SUM_PROD_SELL_QTY'].shift(1)
```